# The PyInstaller problem. Detecting exe as a virus

Tags: exe, pyinstaller

I have created an exe using py installer from my code in python. I checked on VirusTotal is it safe. It wasn't. I have made some reserch and eventually i found what is a problem. It depends on the pyinstaller. My code isn't dangerous or destructive. How can i fix this problem or how to make an exe without "virus".

Thank you in advance

Comment: Contact VirusTotal about this issue, so that they can fix the false positive.

Comment: The virus detects also gmail. Its not a VirusTotal problem

Comment: If VirusTotal is detecting your app as a virus, and it is not, then the issue is with VirusTotal and false detection - it's making a mistake, and they're the ones that can fix things so that the mistake doesn't happen.